# Get value from PHP json_decode

Tags: php, json

a website as https://api.site.tld/myvalue returns a JSON object:

```
{
    "alpha": "first",
    "beta": "second",
    "charlie": "third"
}
```

This code returns instead "Trying to get property 'beta' of non-object..."

```
$org = "https://api.site.tld/$mvalue";
$character = json_decode($org);
echo $character->beta;
```

Where I wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Try `echo $character->{'beta'};` instead. Cfr. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: always the same error

Comment: What is the input that `$org` has, and what is the output (value of `$character`)? `var_dump()` them both for us

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the content of the webpage first. Then you can decode it :

```
$org = "https://api.site.tld/$mvalue";
$content = file_get_contents($org);
$character = json_decode($content);
echo $character->beta;
```

Comment: this 
`
$org = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=mykey&ip=8.8.8.8";
$content = fsockopen($org);
$character = json_decode($content);
echo $character->country;
`

returns:

`
Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in 
Notice: Trying to get property 'country' of non-object in
`

Comment: `fsockopen()` returns a file handler, not the content of the webpage. You need to use calls to `fgets()` or `fread()` to read the content of the "file" (webpage) you opened (or use `file_get_contents` like in my example, that works with URLs too and does all the job in one call)